# Python Multithreading with QThread and Threading Modules

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread, pyqtgraph

I try to start a Qthread and another thread in a program. The codes are shown below. Qthread have to show graphics. Qthread works fine when alone but when i try to run with a thread or multiple Qthread it doesnt show anything.

My setup: **ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, python 2.7.12**

Modules: pyqtgraph, time, numpy, sys, threading

QThread: **plotthread.py**

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
class guiThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.status=True
        self.range=100
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.stop)
        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Example")
        self.win.resize(500,400)
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        self.px = self.win.addPlot(title="X plot")
        self.ckx = self.px.plot(pen='y')
        self.cdx = self.px.plot(pen='r')
        self.px.setXRange(0, self.range)
        self.px.setYRange(-180, 180)
        self.px.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateplot)
        self.timer.start(0.001)
        self.kx=np.zeros(self.range)
        self.dx=np.zeros(self.range)

    def updateplot(self):
        self.ckx.setData(self.kx)
        self.cdx.setData(self.dx)

    def append(self,sin):
        self.kx=np.roll(self.kx,-1)
        self.kx[-1]=sin[0]
        self.dx=np.roll(self.dx,-1)
        self.dx[-1]=int(sin[1])
    def stop(self):
        print "Exit" #exit when window closed
        self.status=False
        sys.exit()
    def run(self):
        print "run" #Qthread run
        while self.status:
            sin=np.random.randint(-180,180,2) 
            self.append(sin) #append random number for plot
            time.sleep(0.01)
```

Python Threading: **ptiming.py**

```
import  time
import threading

class timeThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name=name
        self.t=time.time()
        self.elapsed=0
    def run(self):
        print "thread start"
        while (1):
            self.elapsed=time.time()-self.t
            print self.name, self.elapsed
```

Main: **main.py**

```
import ptiming
import plotthread
t1=plotthread.guiThread()
t1.start()
t2=ptiming.timeThread("t1")
t2.start()
```

Comment: Did you try to add a `win.show()` in your `guiThread` constructor ?

Comment: You cannot perform gui operations of any kind in a separate thread. All gui operations **must** happen in the main thread.

Comment: @mguijarr yes i did in the init and run functions of plotthread

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried plotthread as main thread (not just class) and try to call ptiming in it still same. (As a class everything is ok.)

Comment: @ekhumoro: you're right, but in this case the UI elements are created in the main thread (as it is done in class constructor) and updates are handled by a timer - so it should be ok in term of thread safety

Comment: @mguijarr. That's true, but it's not clear what the intention is, given how the code is currently structured. The OP also says: "QThread have to show graphics". So it's quite hard to understand what the OP is really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `timeThread` class, the `.run()` method does a busy loop: it continuously display elapsed time, without any pause so CPU goes crazy and I guess the OS is not scheduling the other thread, then.

Do a `time.sleep()` of some sort in this loop - should go back to normal.

Side comment: why are you creating UI elements in the guiThread class constructor ? With Qt, in any case all UI elements belong to the main thread. As @ekhumoro said, GUI operations *must* happen in the main thread, and this is the case in your code, although it is written in a confusing way. Personally I would make it obvious UI elements are created in the main thread, and I would add a data processing thread.